# Why I get error like this using SetBitmapAsync()?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, win-universal-app

I'm new to UWP app development and trying to build an image processing app. I was using the code in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/imaging However I got exception like this:
**SoftwareBitmapSource::SetBitmapAsync only supports SoftwareBitmap with positive width/height, bgra8 pixel format and pre-multiplied or no alpha**. in code `await source.SetBitmapAsync(sbitmap);` I'm wondering if this method really has so many limitations and if so if there is any alternative I should use that has the least limitations. The code snippet is as following

```
FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
fileOpenPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

var inputFile = await fileOpenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if(inputFile != null)
{
    SoftwareBitmap sbitmap;
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await inputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        sbitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
    }
    var source = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
    await source.SetBitmapAsync(sbitmap);
    **Exception--->**imageControl.Source = source;
}
```

Comment: So what are the width/height? is it bgra8 pixel format? is there no alpha or a pre-multiplied one?

Comment: @MXD I just selected some default pictures inside the Gallery, none can be displayed. Suppose it this function should take normal jpeg files. Do you know any substitution for this method? I'm looking for something that can handle most of the formats. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known issue. For now you can workaround this by using SoftwareBitmap.Convert to get a Bgra8 pre-multiplied SoftwareBitmap to display

```
SoftwareBitmap displayableImage = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(sbitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
```